# What`s wrong with this Eevee Lighting Setup?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows, ambient-occlusion

I have run into some issues with the EEVEE render engine. I want to render a smartphone but the areas around the camera Lens show some weird lighting problems as you can see in the first picture.

The area near the seams is lit up, but in reality, it should be darker near the seam. I have tried to solve the problem with a boolean operation in case it is a topologic issue. I have also enabled ambient occlusion and tweaked the light and shadow settings but it does not help.

I have never really worked with EEVEE.

[image]

Comment: Hi! It would be really helpful if you could share the file     https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Solved: There are more Lighting-Settings in each Lightsource. Tweak this in Combination with the Shadow Cube Size and Cascade Size in the Render Settings is the solution.

This video describes:

[Video Tutorial i`ve used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQd-whJ9r_M)